# Printing an external page after updating (i.e. a receipt) using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a POS system I'm developing. So far, I can get it to display specific items on the page, keep a log of selected items ready for purchase, store and retrieve data from the database, and send data the sale to another page.

However, I want to be able to print that other page.

How would I go about doing this?

This is the function to send the data to the receipt page:

```
// Prints receipt
printReceipt: function()
{
    var $company = "Foo",
        $address = "Bar Avenue",
        $phone = '01234 567890',
        $date = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
        $items = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Qux"],
        $total = 19.97;

    $.post("receipt.php", {company: $company, address: $address, phone: $phone, date: $date, items: $items, total: $total}).done(function()
    {
        /* Print receipt */
    });
},
```

And here is where it receives this data and displays it in receipt.php:

```
<?php
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $items = $_POST['items'];
    $total = $_POST['total'];

    echo "<div id='variables' company='$company' address='$address' phone='$phone' date='$date' items='$items' total='$total'></div>";
?>

<div id='company'>Company</div><br>
<div id='address'>Address</div><br>
<div id='phone'>Phone</div><br>

<ul id='items'><li>Items</li></div>
<p></p>
Thank you
<p></p>
<div id='total'>Total</div>
<div id='date'>Date/Time</div><br>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#company').html($('#variables').attr('company'));
    $('#address').html($('#variables').attr('address'));
    $('#phone').html($('#variables').attr('phone'));
    $('#date').html($('#variables').attr('date'));
    $('#total').html($('#variables').attr('total'));
    $('#vat').html($('#variables').attr('vat'));

    // Empties <ul> and then populates with array
    $('#items').html("");
    for (var item in $('#variables').attr('items'))
    {
        $('#items').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');
    }
</script>
```

Using jQuery, how would I go about printing this out after it has sent the data through?

Also, for future reference, how do I go about removing the printing prompt, so it prints straight away?

Comment: Have you seen the jquery docs about [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) you can receive the html on your callback...

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject your receipt generated code into your current page (the one which makes the post ajax request) and then call `window.print();`

```
// Prints receipt
printReceipt: function()
{
    var $company = "Foo",
        $address = "Bar Avenue",
        $phone = '01234 567890',
        $date = new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
        $items = ["Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Qux"],
        $total = 19.97;

    $.post("receipt.php", {company: $company, address: $address, phone: $phone, date: $date, items: $items, total: $total}).done(function(data)
    {
        /* Inject receipt code and ask for print */
        $('body').html(data);
        window.print();
    });
},
```

Be careful of you `receipt.php` file, you are using `$_POST` variables without securing them. Why don't you use directly your PHP data into you HTML instead of using javascript ?

```
<?php
    $company = strip_tags($_POST['company']);
    $address = strip_tags($_POST['address']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
    $date = strip_tags($_POST['date']);
    $items = $_POST['items'];
    $total = strip_tags($_POST['total']);
?>

<div id='company'><?php echo $company; ?></div>
<div id='address'><?php echo $address; ?></div>
<div id='phone'><?php echo $phone; ?></div>

<ul id='items'><?php 
    foreach($items as $index => $item) {
    ?><li id="item-<?php echo $index; ?>"><?php echo strip_tags($item); ?></li><?php
    } 
?></ul>
<p>Thank you</p>
<div id='total'><?php echo $total; ?></div>
<div id='date'><?php echo $date; ?></div><br>
```